# How to modify Tomcat related changes in GGTS

Tags: xml, eclipse, tomcat, grails, groovy

I have a grails app project and running it via run-app command in GGTS. I want to change the context.xml of the in-built Tomcat that GGTS/grails uses.

For e.g., I want to add sessionCookiePath="/" to the context.xml for session sharing. I am not able to find the location of the xml files. I checked the folders (under .grails) where something related to Tomcat but I am not able to find the Tomcat conf related files.

Is there a way to add sessionCookiePath="/" via Config.groovy of the app project?? or Can I get to the actual context.xml of the in built tomcat?? or should I have to take completely different approach??

Comment: Is this any use? http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-configure-context-xml-aliases-for-Tomcat-7-td4632149.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I used the link suggested by tim_yates and was able to configure the sessionCookiePath. In case if somebody looking for the answer to set the sessionCookiePath use this.

1. Under the grails project->scripts->_Events.groovy (create _Events.groovy if there isn't one)
2. Add the eventConfigureTomcat like below

   ```
   eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    if (GrailsUtil.environment == 'development')
    {
       def ctx=tomcat.host.findChild(serverContextPath) // serverContextPath is auto injected or you can use the actual server context for e.g., "/app1"
       ctx.sessionCookiePath = '/'
    }
   }
   ```